# Error : Could not find End Of Central Directory

Tags: unix, java, weblogic, ant

I am trying to deploy a war on weblogic9 using an ant task on a Unix box. I am getting the following error :
**[wldeploy] Error opening file [file path] Could not find End Of Central Directory.**
The war file has the name similar to a datasource. This error only occurs if the war file name matches with a datasource. The war gets successfully deployed of the name is different than a datasource in weblogic.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds a lot like a corrupted JAR / WAR / EAR file. Try to upload it again. Or try to make sure there is no conflicting file on the WL server where it tries to unzip it ...

Comment: (And try a zip utility (perhaps `jar`) to see if it is really corrupt.)